# How to make symbolic links point to files inside a docker container when mounting a directory

Tags: docker, symlink, mount

I have created a symbolic link to a file on a host machine. Then I have mounted a directory which contains the file and the link to a docker container. I expect the link inside the container to point to the file inside the container. However it points to the file on host, so it is broken inside the container. Is there a way to make all the links inside a container point to files inside a container and links on host point to files on host? Note that I wouldn't like to modify the links itself.

An example:

```
cd /home/myuser/work/tmp
touch a.txt
ln -s "$(pwd)"/a.txt b.link
docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/some ubuntu bash
ls -lah /some/b.link
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1010 1014 30 Mar 10 13:45 /some/b.link -> /home/myuser/work/tmp/a.txt
```

Expected output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1010 1014 30 Mar 10 13:45 /some/b.link -> /some/a.txt
```

Comment: It should work with relative paths, if that would fit your needs: `ln -s a.txt b.link`

Comment: You can't do that. If you have absolute path then it won't work, only way would be to mount the path inside container as well. If it is relative path then it will work

Comment: Thank you. However I need to handle absolute paths also. Maybe is there some tricky way in linux container to treat symbolic link paths from current directory as other paths. For example, if I see a symlink to some file inside /home/myuser/work/tmp, I treat it as a link to file inside /some

Comment: For that you need to place another link inside the container that points from `/home/myuser/work/tmp` to `/some`. I think it would be better to simply mount `/home/myuser/work/tmp` inside the container. Or think of a way to avoid using links (relative are evil too).

Comment: If you're bind-mounting the host directory into the container, it literally is the same symlink, and it can't have different values in the two different contexts.